# Convert a file from using one date format to another

Tags: perl, shell, sed, awk

I have a bunch of files that contain a bunch of quotes in the following csv format:

```
"Date","Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
12/30/2002,0930,24.53,24.65,24.53,24.65,762200
12/30/2002,0931,24.65,24.68,24.52,24.6,90400
```

I need to convert the file(s) to a new file(s) with almost the same name (for example file.txt to file-NTF.txt) to look like this:

```
"Date Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
20021230 093000;24.53;24.65;24.53;24.65;762200
20021230 093100;24.65;24.68;24.52;24.6;90400
```

So the date and time columns got merged into one, and the format for the date is different is different. Also the commas became semi-colon. I got this far in awk

```
awk -F "," '{print $1,$2}' file.txt
```

which would print the date and time of the original file, but now I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'NR>1{print $3$1$2" "$4"00",$5,$6,$7,$8,$9;next}{sub(/","/," ")}1' FS='[/,]' OFS=';' file
"Date Time","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"
20021230 093000;24.53;24.65;24.53;24.65;762200
20021230 093100;24.65;24.68;24.52;24.6;90400
```

Comment: Sweet!! Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{
  print "\"Date Time\";\"Open\";\"High\";\"Low\";\"Close\";\"Volume\""
}
NR>1 {
  printf("%04d%02d%02d %04d00;%s;%s;%s;%s\n", \
    substr($1,7,4), substr($1,1,2), substr($1,4,2),  $2, \
    $3, $4, $5, $6 $7)
}' file
```

**output**

```
"Date Time";"Open";"High";"Low";"Close";"Volume"
20021230 093000;24.53;24.65;24.53;24.65762200
20021230 093100;24.65;24.68;24.52;24.690400
```

I have taken the liberty of using the field separator that you show in your sample output records and use that in the Header as well. commas as delimiters are a hassle, IHMO.

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '1{s/","/ /;b};s/^(..).(..).(....).(....)/\3\1\2 \400/;y/,/;/' file
```

For the first line only replace the first double-quote, comma double-quote by space.

For second and subsequent lines apply the substitution and the translation.

However to replace all commas by semi-colons use:

```
sed -r '1s/","/ /;1!s/^(..).(..).(....).(....)/\3\1\2 \400/;y/,/;/' file
```